# Proof check for generalization of integration by parts

Tags: partial-differential-equations, summation, solution-verification

By the way, $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesgue measure (I didn't choose to denote the Lebesgue measure in this way).

$\mathbf{Lemma \;\, 0.1.}$ For any $\hat{\alpha} \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{n}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha+e_{j}} \frac{1}{\alpha !}=\frac{|\hat{\alpha}|}{\hat{\alpha} !}
\end{align*}
$Proof.$ Fix $\hat{\alpha}=\left(\hat{\alpha}_{1}, \ldots, \hat{\alpha}_{n}\right) \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{n}$. Define $I:=\left\{j \in\{1, \ldots, n\}: \hat{\alpha}_{j} \neq 0\right\},$ and observe that we have
\begin{align*}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha+e_{j}} \frac{1}{\alpha !} &=\sum_{j \in I} \frac{1}{\left(\hat{\alpha}-e_{j}\right) !} \\
&=\sum_{j \in I} \frac{\hat{\alpha}_{j} !}{\hat{\alpha} !\left(\hat{\alpha}_{j}-1\right) !} \\
&=\sum_{j \in I} \frac{\hat{a}_{j}}{\hat{a} !} \\
&=\frac{1}{\hat{a} !} \sum_{j \in I} \hat{\alpha}_{j} \\
&=\frac{|\hat{\alpha}|}{\hat{a} !}
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
$\mathbf{Theorem \;\, 0.2.}$ Let $U$ be a bounded, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\partial U$ is a $C^{1}$ surface. Define $\sigma$ to be the surface measure on the surface $\partial U .$ Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{n}$ and $f, g \in C^{|\alpha|}(\bar{U})$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{U}\left(\partial^{\alpha} f\right) g d \mathcal{L}^{n}=(-1)^{|\alpha|} \int_{U} f\left(\partial^{\alpha} g\right) d \mathcal{L}^{n}+\sum_{l=1}^{|\alpha|} \sum_{\substack{\alpha=\beta+\gamma+e_j
    \\ |\gamma|=l-1
    \\ |\beta|=|\alpha|-l}} (-1)^{l+1} \frac{\alpha !(|\alpha|-l) !(l-1) !}{|\alpha| ! \beta ! \gamma !} \int_{\partial U} \nu_{j} \cdot\left(\partial^{\beta} f\right)\left(\partial^{\gamma} g\right) d \sigma \tag{$1$}.
\end{align*}
$Proof.$ Observe that if $|\alpha|=1,$ then $\alpha=e_{j}$ for some $j \in\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and for $f,g \in C^1(\bar{U})$ we have that $(1)$ is the formula for integration by parts which we have already seen to be an immediate consequence of the Divergence Theorem applied to the function $h=f g \in C^{1}(\bar{U})$ and the vector field $\mathbf{H}_{j}=f g e_{j} \in C^{1}\left(\bar{U} ; \mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$. Fix $M \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose $(1)$ holds whenever $f, g \in C^{M}(\bar{U})$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{n}$ with $|\alpha|=M$. Let $\hat{\alpha}\in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{n}$ with $|\hat{\alpha}|=M+1,$ and let $f, g \in C^{|\hat{\alpha}|}(\bar{U}) .$ So we have

\begin{align}
\int_U (\partial^{\hat{\alpha}} f)g d \mathcal{L}^n &=  \frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|} \left(\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \frac{1}{\alpha!} \right) \int_U (\partial^{\hat{\alpha}} f)g d \mathcal{L}^n \notag
  \\&= \frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|} \left(\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \frac{1}{\alpha!} \int_U \left( \partial^\alpha (\partial_j f) \right) g d \mathcal{L}^n \right) \notag
 \\&=\frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|}\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \sum_{l=1}^{|\alpha|} \sum_{\substack{\alpha=\beta+\gamma+e_j \notag
    \\ |\gamma|=l-1
    \\ |\beta|=|\alpha|-l}} (-1)^{l+1} \frac{(|\alpha|-l)!(l-1)!}{|\alpha|!\beta! \gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j \cdot \left(\partial^\beta (\partial_j f) \right)(\partial^{\gamma} g) d \sigma
    \\&+\frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|}\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \frac{1}{\alpha!} (-1)^{|\alpha|} \int_U (\partial_j f)(\partial^\alpha g) d \mathcal{L}^n \notag
    \\&=\frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|}\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \sum_{l=1}^{|\alpha|} \sum_{\substack{\alpha=\beta+\gamma+e_j
    \\ |\gamma|=l-1
    \\ |\beta|=|\alpha|-l}} (-1)^{l+1} \frac{(|\alpha|-l)!(l-1)!}{|\alpha|!\beta! \gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j \cdot \left(\partial^\beta (\partial_j f) \right)(\partial^{\gamma} g) d \sigma \notag
    \\&+\frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|}\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \frac{1}{\alpha!} (-1)^{|\alpha|}\left[-\int_U f (\partial^{\alpha+e_j}g)d \mathcal{L}^n  + \int_{\partial U} \nu_j \cdot f(\partial^{\alpha} g) d \sigma \right] \notag
    \\&=\frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|}\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \Bigg[ \sum_{l=1}^{|\alpha|} \sum_{\substack{\alpha=\beta+\gamma+e_j
    \\ |\gamma|=l-1
    \\ |\beta|=|\alpha|-l}} (-1)^{l+1} \frac{(|\alpha|-l)!(l-1)!}{|\alpha|!\beta! \gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j  \cdot \left(\partial^\beta (\partial_j f) \right)(\partial^{\gamma} g) d \sigma \notag
    \\&  + (-1)^{|\alpha|} \frac{1}{\alpha!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j \cdot f(\partial^{\alpha} g) d \sigma \Bigg]+ \frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|}\Bigg(\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \frac{1}{\alpha!} (-1)^{|\alpha+e_j|}\int_U f (\partial^{\alpha+e_j}g)d \mathcal{L}^n \Bigg) \notag
    \\&= \frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|}\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \Bigg[ \sum_{l=1}^{|\alpha|}  \sum_{\substack{\alpha+e_j=\hat{\beta}+\gamma+e_j
    \\ |\gamma|=l-1
    \\ |\hat{\beta}|=|\alpha|-l+1}} \left( \sum_{\hat{\beta}=\beta +e_j} \frac{1}{\beta!} \right)(-1)^{l+1} \frac{(|\alpha|-l)!(l-1)!}{|\alpha|! \gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j  \cdot \left(\partial^{\hat{\beta}} f \right)(\partial^{\gamma} g) d \sigma \notag
    \\&  +  \sum_{\alpha=\gamma+e_j} (-1)^{|\alpha|+2} \frac{1}{|\alpha|\gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j \cdot f(\partial^{\alpha} g) d \sigma \Bigg] + \frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|} \Bigg(\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \frac{1}{\alpha!} \Bigg)(-1)^{|\hat{\alpha}|}\int_U f (\partial^{\hat{\alpha}}g)d \mathcal{L}^n \notag
    \\&=\frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|}\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \Bigg[ \sum_{l=1}^{|\alpha|}  \sum_{\substack{\alpha+e_j=\hat{\beta}+\gamma+e_j
    \\ |\gamma|=l-1
    \\ |\hat{\beta}|=|\alpha|-l+1}} \frac{|\hat{\beta}|}{\hat{\beta}!} (-1)^{l+1} \frac{(|\alpha|-l)!(l-1)!}{|\alpha|! \gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j  \cdot \left(\partial^{\hat{\beta}} f \right)(\partial^{\gamma} g) d \sigma \notag
    \\&  +  \sum_{\alpha=\gamma+e_j} (-1)^{|\alpha+e_j|+1} \frac{1}{|\alpha|\gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j \cdot f(\partial^{\alpha} g) d \sigma \Bigg] + (-1)^{|\hat{\alpha}|}\int_U f (\partial^{\hat{\alpha}}g)d \mathcal{L}^n \notag
    \\&=\frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|}\sum_{\hat{\alpha}=\alpha +e_j} \Bigg[ \sum_{l=1}^{|\alpha+e_j|}  \sum_{\substack{\alpha+e_j=\hat{\beta}+\gamma+e_j
    \\ |\gamma|=l-1
    \\ |\hat{\beta}|=|\alpha+e_j|-l}} (-1)^{l+1} \frac{(|\alpha+e_j|-l)!(l-1)!}{|\alpha|! \hat{\beta}! \gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j  \cdot \left(\partial^{\hat{\beta}} f \right)(\partial^{\gamma} g) d \sigma \Bigg] \notag
    \\&  + (-1)^{|\hat{\alpha}|}\int_U f (\partial^{\hat{\alpha}}g)d \mathcal{L}^n \notag
    \\&=\frac{\hat{\alpha}!}{|\hat{\alpha}|}\sum_{l=1}^{|\hat{\alpha}|}  \sum_{\substack{\hat{\alpha}=\hat{\beta}+\gamma+e_j
    \\ |\gamma|=l-1
    \\ |\hat{\beta}|=|\hat{\alpha}|-l}} (-1)^{l+1} \frac{(|\hat{\alpha}|-l)!(l-1)!}{|\hat{\alpha}-1|! \hat{\beta}! \gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j  \cdot \left(\partial^{\hat{\beta}} f \right)(\partial^{\gamma} g) d \sigma + (-1)^{|\hat{\alpha}|}\int_U f (\partial^{\hat{\alpha}}g)d \mathcal{L}^n \notag 
     \\&=\sum_{l=1}^{|\hat{\alpha}|} \sum_{\substack{\hat{\alpha}=\hat{\beta}+\gamma+e_j
    \\ |\gamma|=l-1
    \\ |\hat{\beta}|=|\hat{\alpha}|-l}} (-1)^{l+1} \frac{\hat{\alpha}! (|\hat{\alpha}|-l)!(l-1)!}{|\hat{\alpha}|!\hat{\beta}! \gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j \cdot (\partial^{\hat{\beta}}f)(\partial^{\gamma} g) d \sigma+ (-1)^{|\hat{\alpha}|}\int_U f (\partial^{\hat{\alpha}}g)d \mathcal{L}^n.\tag{$2$}\end{align}

For the first equality in $(2)$ we have used Lemma $0.1$, for the third equality we have applied our inductive hypothesis to $\partial_j f, g \in C^M \left(\bar{U}\right)$ 
 [$f \in C^{|\hat{\alpha}|}\left(\bar{U}\right) \land |\hat{\alpha}|=M+1 \implies \partial_j f \in C^M\left(\bar{U}\right)$], for the fourth equality we have applied the integration by parts formula to $f, \partial^\alpha g \in C^1\left(\bar{U}\right)$  
  [$g \in C^{|\hat{\alpha}|}\left(\bar{U}\right) \land |\hat{\alpha}|=|\alpha|+1 \implies \partial^\alpha g \in C^1\left(\bar{U}\right)$], for the sixth inequality we have again used Lemma $0.1$, and finally for the seventh equality we have once again used Lemma $0.1$ (technically it is used in two instances here). Thus by induction on $|\alpha|$, we have

\begin{equation*}
    \int_U (\partial^\alpha f)g d \mathcal{L}^n = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \int_U f(\partial^\alpha g) d \mathcal{L}^n + \sum_{l=1}^{|\alpha|} \sum_{\substack{\alpha=\beta+\gamma+e_j
    \\ |\gamma|=l-1
    \\ |\beta|=|\alpha|-l}} (-1)^{l+1} \frac{\alpha! (|\alpha|-l)!(l-1)!}{|\alpha|!\beta! \gamma!} \int_{\partial U} \nu_j \cdot (\partial^{\beta}f)(\partial^{\gamma} g) d \sigma . \end{equation*}
whenever $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}_0^n$ and $f,g \in C^{|\alpha|}\left(\bar{U}\right)$.